# Update mysql columns field value from other columns of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table named `categories` 
with fields like

```
Category_id, Category_name, Category_sorted
1             food             0
2             drinks           0
3             milk             0
4             snacks           0
....
2421          other            0
```

Here I want to update all the `category_id` values into `category_sorted` so that it should be like

```
Category_id, Category_name, Category_sorted
1             food             1
2             drinks           2
3             milk             3
4             snacks           4
....
2421          other            2421
```

I can do this with PHP, but I wanted to know if it is possible to update the same with single mysql query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should be pretty straight forward,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    category_sorted = category_ID
```